# Combining multiple columns in R to get frequency count?

Tags: r, data-preprocessing, frequency

I have incident data and for each incident, there are multiple individuals each with sex/age. The data looks something like this:

| incident | person1 | personl1sex | person1age | person2 | person2sex | person2age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 10 | B | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | A | 0 | 10 |  |  |  |
| 3 | B | 1 | 5 | C | 0 | 7 |
| 4 | A | 0 | 10 | C | 0 | 7 |
| 5 | C | 0 | 7 | A | 0 | 10 |

There can be up to 8 persons per incident (row).

I want to count frequencies of

1. individual IDs,
2. sexes,
3. ages.

The order of the persons per incident doesn't matter. Is there an easier way (I'm sure there is) to count frequencies without having to do `count(data$person1)`, `count(data$person2)` etc and summing them all together?

The persons are `col_character` and the ages and sexes are `col_double` - in case that matters and they need to be reformatted.